# split string in single lines and save the data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to split array in single lines and save it to xml file. It is about IpAddress. You can put some strings under each other. But now it is one long string

I have this:

```
internal void Deserialize(Product product) {
        XElement settings = XElement.Parse(product.AuthenticationSettings ?? "<settings/>");

        if (settings == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired") == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired").Value != "true")
            return;

        XElement conditions = settings.Element("preconditions");
        if (conditions == null)
            return;

        //XElement[] conditions2 = settings.Element[("preconditions")];
        //if (conditions == null)
        //    return;


        XElement condition = conditions.Element("residentsonly");
        if (condition!= null)
            this.ResidentsOnly = (condition.Value == "1");

        condition = conditions.Element("minimumage");
        if (condition != null) {
            int age = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(condition.Value, out age))
                this.MinimumAge = age;
        }

        condition = conditions.Element("redirecturl");
        if (condition != null) {
            this.RedirectUrl = condition.Value;
        }

   condition = conditions.Element("ipaddress");
        if (condition != null) {

            string[] lines =  IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            //condition = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
                if ( lines[i] != null){
                lines[i] = condition.Value.ToString();
            }
                //lines = string.Join("\n", condition.Value.ToArray());
            }


        }
    }
```

it is about IPaddress.

But the problem is lines is always null. Thank you.

This is the IpAddress:

```
 [Display(Name = "PreConditionIpAddress", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
```

This is my serialize method:

```
internal string Serialize(EditProductModel model) {
            if (this.ResidentsOnly == false && this.MinimumAge == 0)
                return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

            XElement settings = XElement.Parse(model.Product.AuthenticationSettings ?? "<settings/>");
            if (settings == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired") == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired").Value != "true")
                return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

            settings.Add(
                new XElement("preconditions",
                    new XElement("residentsonly", this.ResidentsOnly ? "1" : "0"),
                    new XElement("minimumage", this.MinimumAge),
                    new XElement("redirecturl", this.RedirectUrl),
                    new XElement("ipaddress", this.IpAddress)
                )
            );

            return settings.ToString();
        }
```

I have it now like this:

```
public class PreConditionSettings
    {
        [Display(Name = "PreConditionResidentsOnly", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public bool ResidentsOnly { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "PreConditionMinimumAge", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public int MinimumAge { get; set; }

        [SfsHelpers.PreConditionRedirectValidation(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product), ErrorMessageResourceName="PreConditionRedirectUrlValidation")]
        [Display(Name = "PreConditionRedirectUrl", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "PreConditionIpAddress", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }

        public PreConditionSettings() {
            this.ResidentsOnly = false;
            this.MinimumAge = 0;
            this.RedirectUrl = null;
            this.IpAddress = null;
        }


        public static string[] replacer(Dictionary<string, string> dic, string IpAddress)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dic) {
                IpAddress = IpAddress.Replace(entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }
            string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            return lines;
        }

        internal string Serialize(EditProductModel model) {
            if (this.ResidentsOnly == false && this.MinimumAge == 0)
                return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

            XElement settings = XElement.Parse(model.Product.AuthenticationSettings ?? "<settings/>");
            if (settings == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired") == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired").Value != "true")
                return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

            settings.Add(
                new XElement("preconditions",
                    new XElement("residentsonly", this.ResidentsOnly ? "1" : "0"),
                    new XElement("minimumage", this.MinimumAge),
                    new XElement("redirecturl", this.RedirectUrl),
                    new XElement("ipaddress", this.IpAddress)
                )
            );

            return settings.ToString();
        }

        internal void Deserialize(EditProductModel model) {
            Deserialize(model.Product);
        }

        internal void Deserialize(Product product) {
            XElement settings = XElement.Parse(product.AuthenticationSettings ?? "<settings/>");

            if (settings == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired") == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired").Value != "true")
                return;

            XElement conditions = settings.Element("preconditions");
            if (conditions == null)
                return;            

            XElement condition = conditions.Element("residentsonly");
            if (condition!= null)
                this.ResidentsOnly = (condition.Value == "1");

            condition = conditions.Element("minimumage");
            if (condition != null) {
                int age = 0;
                if (Int32.TryParse(condition.Value, out age))
                    this.MinimumAge = age;
            }

            condition = conditions.Element("redirecturl");
            if (condition != null) {
                this.RedirectUrl = condition.Value;
            }           



            condition = conditions.Element("ipaddress");             
            if (condition != null) {

                IpAddress = "";
                Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                dic.Add("<ipaddress>", string.Empty);
                dic.Add("</ipaddress>", string.Empty);
                dic.Add(" ", Environment.NewLine);
                replacer(dic, IpAddress);
                this.IpAddress = condition.Value;


            }
        }
    }
```

Now the output is: 777777
99999999
8888888
.

But it has to be:

```
<ipaddress>77777777</ipaddress>
<ipaddress>99999999999</ipaddress>
<ipaddress>888888888888</ipaddress>
```

Thank you

Comment: where is `IpAddress` declared? what is it?

Comment: Thank you. I Edit the post. IpAddress = null

Comment: if IpAdress is null, why do you expect the Split operation to return something other than null?

Comment: But: condition = <ipaddress>66666
888888</ipaddress> but that has to be 2 strings

Comment: So how to improve? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, condition = <ipaddress>66666 888888</ipaddress>  is this the end result you want, or is this the end result you are getting? 

what is the actual value you get from IpAddress and what is your expected outcome?

Comment: You can put many strings in textbox, like: 88888, 99999 - under each other. But now it is saved as one long string and not different strings

Comment: so if the input is 88888, 99999, then split by space will work for you? 
such as 
IpAddress.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)

then you can line break it if you want or create different tag to differentiate from each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

Here's the method call:

```
        string someData = "";
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dic.Add("<ipaddress>", string.Empty);
        dic.Add("</ipaddress>", string.Empty);
        dic.Add(" ", Environment.NewLine);
        string[] data = replacer(dic, someData);
        data = wrapper(data, "ipaddress");
        string result = combiner(data);
```

Here's the method itself:

```
    public static string[] replacer(Dictionary<string,string> dic, string data) 
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> entry in dic)
        {
            data = data.Replace(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
        string[] delimiters = new string[] { Environment.NewLine, " " };
        string[] lines =  data.Split(delimiters ,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        return lines;
    }


public static string[] wrapper(string[] data, string tag)
{
   string tagOpen, tagClose;
   tagOpen = "<" + tag + ">";
   tagClose = "</" + tag + ">";
   for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
   {
       data[i] = tagOpen + data[i] + tagClose;
   }

   return data;
}


public static string combiner(string[] data)
{
   string res = string.Empty;
   for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
   {
       res += data[i] + Environment.NewLine;
   }

   return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But the strings ofcourse not hardcoded. A user can enter any Ipaddress what he/she want.

Comment: Of course, that just an example of how you can do it, however you can use some generic version of this, so you can choose what to replace and by what. Edited the answer

Comment: But how to get it working with the condition? Thank you

Comment: I think if you just replace IpAddress = ""; with IpAddress = condition.Value; it should do the trick

Comment: I edited my answer, tried to make it reusable. Feel free to ask more questions and of course to upvote and mark as answered.

Comment: Hi Felix, I have sent you email

Comment: I only get this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'  on this line:  char[] delimiters = new char [] { Environment.NewLine, ' '};

Comment: edited, Enviroment.NewLine is used as string not char